# How do you use Geth to send a transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions

I want to send ether from one account to another using the geth client. I don't want to wait several days or use up tens of gigs on my hard drive before doing so either. How can this be done?

Comment: Hi there. Can you reformulate your post into a question, please? At the minute it's unclear what you're asking, if anything at all :-)

Comment: Is this still unclear in some way? I think it's pretty straightforward now...

Comment: I have no idea why this got closed. It is a clear question with detailed steps for the answer. Almost seems like a blatant abuse of admin power.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Use light mode when starting geth. If you don't it will try and download the entire block chain, which uses a significant amount of space and could take days.

   To use light mode, do `geth --syncmode "light"`
2. In another terminal, create a file with the following contents:

   ```
   function checkAllBalances() {
       var totalBal = 0;
       for (var acctNum in eth.accounts) {
           var acct = eth.accounts[acctNum];
           var acctBal = web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(acct), "ether");
           totalBal += parseFloat(acctBal);
           console.log("  eth.accounts[" + acctNum + "]: \t" + acct + " \tbalance: " + acctBal + " ether");
       }
       console.log("  Total balance: " + totalBal + " ether");
   };
   ```

   Note the path to this file as it will be needed later.
3. Attach to the running geth instance with:
   `geth attach`
4. Load the js from step 2 into the console with: `loadScript("/path/to/file.js")`
5. Check your balance with: `checkAllBalances();` Ensure you have enough both to send and cover the transaction cost. You may have to wait a few minutes for the light client to get the needed values.
6. Unlock your account with `personal.unlockAccount('yourAddressHere');` You will be prompted for your password. I prefer this approach to passing the password as a second parameter to the `unlockAccount` function as you don't ever have it in plain text.
7. Send Ether with the `eth.sendTransaction` function, e.g. `eth.sendTransaction({from:'fromAddress', to:'toAddress', value: web3.toWei(0.05, "ether"), gas:21000});`

You should get a receipt value in hex. You can use `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt("receiptHash")` to see details, with status of "0x1" meaning success. This may take some time. You can also use the receipt on sites like https://etherscan.io or https://etherchain.org to see details on the transaction by simply entering the hex value in the search bar on the respective site.